# Get the selected pivot table name - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have two pivot tables on one excel sheet. I would like to know how do you get the name of a selected pivot table with Excel VBA?

I tried `ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Selected`, but this is not a supported property.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You simply use:

```
ActiveCell.PivotTable.Name
```

or, with a bit of error handling:

```
Dim PT as PivotTable
On Error Resume Next
Set PT = Activecell.PivotTable
On Error Goto 0
If not PT is nothing then msgbox pt.name
```